# HTTP Range Requests to files with precompressed components - Support for native browser decompression?

Tags: javascript, http

I'd like to store multiple individually compressed chunks of data into a single large file. Individual chunks are fetched with range requests and ideally, I'd like the browser to automatically decompress the data.

- A file is tens of gigabytes big and consists of millions of chunks. Each chunk is, e.g. gzip or brotli compressed.
- I'd like to fetch a chunk with a range request, and I'd like to make use of browser capabilities to automatically decompress the gzip or brotli compressed chunks.
- The server is a file server. No server side application is deployed that could alter the response header.
- Users often don't have the possibility to configure the server, so standard server settings should work.

Is this somehow possible? I know I could probably use a javascript decompressor but I'd expect native browser capabilities to be faster and easier to use, provided it is possible at all.

Thanks!